# Reading an XML document with XMLDocument C# 'password' string not returning

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I'm trying to read the text in between `<keyMaterial></keyMaterial>`

I tried using `//WLANProfile/MSM/security/sharedKey` as the element route, seen in the code below. It refuses to return a value. I have run through the debugger and after the breakpoint at the line: `XmlNodeList sharedKeyNodes = wifiProfile.SelectNodes("//WLANProfile/MSM/security/sharedKey");`

the SharedKeyNodes object doesn't return a count for. I know it's just a matter of figuring out the element route so I'm not coming here completely hopeless...

```
System.Xml.XPathNodeList
```

My XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<WLANProfile xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1">
    <name>nosignal</name>
    <SSIDConfig>
        <SSID>
            <hex>6E6F7369676E616C</hex>
            <name>nosignal</name>
        </SSID>
        <nonBroadcast>true</nonBroadcast>
    </SSIDConfig>
    <connectionType>ESS</connectionType>
    <connectionMode>auto</connectionMode>
    <autoSwitch>false</autoSwitch>
    <MSM>
        <security>
            <authEncryption>
                <authentication>WPA2PSK</authentication>
                <encryption>AES</encryption>
                <useOneX>false</useOneX>
                <FIPSMode xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v2">false</FIPSMode>
            </authEncryption>
            <sharedKey>
                <keyType>passPhrase</keyType>
                <protected>true</protected>
                <keyMaterial>01000000D</keyMaterial>
            </sharedKey>
        </security>
    </MSM>
</WLANProfile>
```

[ EDIT with the help of LB the new code looks like this and it WORKS! ]
[ For anyone that is struggling with a similar problem. ]

My Class is:

```
class ProfileManager
{
    public static string readProfile() {

        XmlDocument wifiProfile = new XmlDocument();


            string path = @"C:\temp\nosignal.xml";
            string password = "";

            wifiProfile.Load(path);

            XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(wifiProfile.NameTable);
            mgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1");

            XmlNodeList sharedKeyNodes = wifiProfile.SelectNodes("//ns:WLANProfile/ns:MSM/ns:security/ns:sharedKey", mgr);

            foreach (XmlNode itemNode in sharedKeyNodes)
            {
                XmlNode keyMaterialNode = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("ns:keyMaterial", mgr);


                if (keyMaterialNode != null)
                {
                    password = keyMaterialNode.InnerText;
                }
            } 


        return password;

    }

}
```

I'm close, but still just a bit stuck. Any help would be appreciated!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't use the default XmlNamespace "http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1"

```
wifiProfile.Load(path);

XmlNamespaceManager mgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(wifiProfile.NameTable);
mgr.AddNamespace("ns", "http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1");

XmlNodeList sharedKeyNodes = wifiProfile.SelectNodes("//ns:WLANProfile/ns:MSM/ns:security/ns:sharedKey",mgr);
```

Comment: I added this and it still isn't returning anything. Thank you for your answer though!

Comment: @ozfive `it still isn't returning anything`? I tested it before posting and it returns **1** result.....

Comment: I'm debugging it now and am not getting a return value for the password string

Comment: @ozfive I am pretty sure you didn't used the namespace for `keyMaterial` :) `XmlNode keyMaterialNode = itemNode.SelectSingleNode("ns:keyMaterial",mgr);` I thought you got the idea....